# Flutter: How to get a File object from ImageProvider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I get a File from an ImageProvider?

```
ImageProvider imageProvider = NetworkImage(networkUrl);
File file = imageProvider ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `ImageProvider` with `NetworkImage` renders the content of your network image URL, it doesn't have direct APIs or easy way for you to be able to convert it to a `File` object. With that said, you can still manually cache (or download) the image/s and get the download stream.

As far as I can understand your question, you are trying to access the network image URL as a `File` object. Instead of using `ImageProvider`, you can take a look at the [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager), which is a plugin used for downloading and caching files locally, and save it for later use.

**Example Usage**

1. Downloading network image file from URL

```
await DefaultCacheManager().downloadFile(url);
```

2. Retrieving `File` object from the cache dir

```
// Retrieving File object
var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(imageUrl);

// File object available for use
// Eg. Reading file as string
file.readAsStringSync(...);
```

**Further reading**

- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager
- https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Comment: Using getSingleFile(url), I'm getting an error : ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)

Comment: What Flutter SDK version are you using?

Comment: flutter_windows_v1.9.1+hotfix.6

Comment: Is that the only error message you can see from the logs?

Comment: That is the first message that appears and then it gets repeated.

Comment: There maybe a conflicting dependency added in your pubspec.yaml, do you mind sharing your pubspec dependency list?

Comment: I was going through the documentation of 'flutter_cache_manager' and came across this : " The file name of the database is the key of the cacheManager, that's why that has to be unique." I will not be able to control the file name to be unique. So this is not the package I would consider using. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: got what I was looking for here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546381/how-to-get-image-from-url-to-a-file-in-flutter/59589480#59589480

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for the heads up. I do have one recommendation for you, it's best if you can write your question/s clearly upfront. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you!